# Пакеты в Java. Объясните ошибки.

Tags: java

Ситуация следующая. jdk1.6.0_25  В каталоге ./test/p программа Cl1.java В CLASSPATH путь до ./test/p прописан. CLASSPATH=.;C:\Documents and Settings\avp\java\src

```
package test.p;

public class Cl1 {
    public Cl1() {
        System.out.println("Cl1 ()");
    }
    public static void priTest() {
        System.out.println("Cl1 test");
    }
    public static void  main (String [] av) {
        System.out.println("Cli main test");
    }
 }
```

А в каталоге ./test программа Tcl1.java

```
import test.p.*;

public class Tcl1 {
    public static void main (String [] av) {    
        Cl1 c = new Cl1();
        c.priTest();
    }
}
```

Выполняем команды

```
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test/p $ javac Cl1.java 
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test/p $ cd ..
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test $ javac Tcl1.java 
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test $ java Tcl1
Cl1 ()
Cl1 test
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test $ 
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test $
```

**Пока все OK**

Копируем Tcl1.java в ./test/p и пытаемся скомпилировать ее **Вопрос номер 1**

```
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test $ cp Tcl1.java p/
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test $ cd p
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test/p $ javac Tcl1.java 
Tcl1.java:7: cannot access Cl1
bad class file: .\Cl1.class
class file contains wrong class: test.p.Cl1
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
    Cl1 c = new Cl1();
    ^
1 error
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test/p $ 
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test/p $
```

Попытка выполнить Cl1.class (ведь в ней есть main() !) **Вопрос номер 2**

```
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test/p $ java Cl1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Cl1 (wrong name: test/p/Cl1)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        .........
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Cl1.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" 
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/java/src/test/p $
```

Естественно, если закомментарить строку с package в Cl1.java , то все компилится и Cl1  работает.

Извините за длинный и наверное бестолковый вопрос, но я читал книжки (видимо недостаточно внимательно), однако не понимаю **почему несовместимы package и main**, а также
почему **класс с main не компилируется в том же оглавлении**, где лежат импортируемые классы. (Однако, скомпилированный в любом другом месте, запускается где угодно).
**Или я что-то элементарное делаю не так ?**

В окне командной строки Windows все точно так же, только копипастить оттуда не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компиляция с **вопросом номер 1** не проходит из-за того, что в `CLASSPATH` встречается класс, находящийся не по тому пути, который соответствует его пакету. А именно: Cl1 принадлежит пакету `test.p`, т.е. должен лежать в директории `test/p` относительно `CLASSPATH`; но при поиске классов компилятор обходит пути в `CLASSPATH` последовательно - и в данном случае первой проверяет текущую директорию `./`, находит там какой-то неправильно расположенный (пакет объявлен вроде `test.p`, а лежит тупо без пакета) класс и ругается. Попробуйте удалить `./` из `CLASSPATH` во время компиляции (или перейти на 2 уровня выше) - и все пройдет ок.

Выполнение с **вопросом номер 2** не работает потому, что вы указываете неквалифицированное имя класса - это ведь не `Cl1`, а `test.p.Cl1`.

Comment: Спасибо !  
Насчет 1) отлично понял. Но все равно без . в CLASSPATH не работает. Уже по причине, что не может найти (при запуска java Tcl1) класс с main. java test\\Tcl1 то же самое - не могу найти  test\\Tcl1. Хотя Tcl1.class там лежит. Т.е все равно **не получилось**.

Насчет 2). Я думал использовать такой прием (main в классе) с целью локального тестирования класса. Но, выходит, **без изменений в тексте** это не получится ?

Comment: 1) ну да, не запускается, потому что из `CLASSPATH` удалили текущую директорию. Кстати, обращаться к `Tcl1` через `test.Tcl1` только потому, что он лежит в `test/`, нельзя - в объявлении класса этот пакет не указан.
2) обычно для тестирования используют JUnit.
Вообще, не совсем понятны эти махинации с перемещением классов и странным расположением пакетов (как-то `test.p` - пакет для Cl1, а `test` для Tcl1 - не пакет). Вы просто изучаете, как оно работает, или хотите чего-то добиться?

Comment: Точно, я просто изучаю, как ведет себя эта штука, которую отливальщики  "Серебряных пуль" сделали для Американских Производителей Пылесосов. А потом уже она (Java) начала жить своей жизнью в новых нишах.